# Django models. How do I make "add new" field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make an OfferUp-like web app using Django Framework. Everything has been going great until I ran into a problem. How could I make it so that users can upload multiple pictures, instead of just one using the `models.ImageField()` function? You know? We might have users that only have 5 pictures to upload, while another user might have 8. How could I make it so that users can upload into the database as many pictures as they want?

Comment: You make an extra model with one `ImageField`, and a `ForeignKey` to the item that should contain multiple pictures.

Comment: Clever that! I will try it

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This is a popular solution for public photos, but what if the photos/files would be private? We are speaking within the scope of the question asked by Juan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm going to suggest isn't that much different from the comment above (i don't have enough reputation to make a comment), so I'm just going to add a code snippet:

```
    class Item(models.Model):
        name = models.TextField()

    class ItemImage(models.Model):
        name = models.TextField()
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

and say: If you have more than one model with many images, rather than repeating the code you can just make a model (class) that will be inherited as the foreign key.

Comment: Thank you. It works great I feel stupid for not thinking about that. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Oh don't be, we learn everyday.  And you are very welcome :)